Finding a limit curve for the binomials.
How would I evaluate this limit?
$$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle \binom{n}{x \sqrt{n} + \frac{n}{2}}}{\displaystyle \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}}$$
I wrote this using binomial coefficients, and am taking the Gamma function for the fraction $\dfrac{n}{2}$. This is meant to shift the center to $0$ and rescale so that the height at $0$ is $1$.

Have you tried using Stirling's formula?

Hint
As usual, go from the binomial coefficinets to the gamma function or to the factorial
$$ \frac{\displaystyle \binom{n}{x \sqrt{n} + \frac{n}{2}}}{\displaystyle \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}}=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)^2}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1-x \sqrt{n}\right)\,\,
   \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1+x \sqrt{n}\right)}$$ Take logarithms and use Stirling approximation
$$\log (\Gamma (p+1))=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} (\log (p)+\log (2 \pi ))+O\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$$
Apply is three times, take the limit and you will find a very simple expression for $f(x)$.

I'm getting much further with this approach, but still stuck. I tried to simplify as much as possible but eventually hit a line with a lot of $n \ln(n)$ and $n \ln(n-4x^2)$ terms and couldn't go on. Do I try and approximate further? How do I know I haven't lost important information?

Write what you obtained using my hint. Do not forget to exponentiate the result.
